# How to use a form from another controller to set a value that has a has_many :through relation in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, has-many-through

Here's my current situation:

I have a model `:companies` and a model `:users`(`Devise`). A company can have many moderating users through a third model `:moderator_connections` and vice versa. To select a current moderator, I've added the column `current_company` (not referenced) to the model `:users`.

I want to add a `dropdown_menu` under my main menu throughout the website. By selecting a current company from this menu, the user can switch to that company's content. I tried to do this by rendering a form-partial above the `<%= yield %>` in my `application.html.erb`. The `form` tries to edit the `current_company` integer (by changing it to the `company_id` of one of the connected companies) for the `current_user`, but I think I'm not even close to solving it :(

Here are my relations.

/models/company.rb:

```
has_many :moderator_connections    
has_many :moderators, through: :moderator_connections, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'company_id'
```

/models/user.rb:

```
has_many :moderator_connections
has_many :moderated_companies, through: :moderator_connections, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

/models/moderator_connection.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <%= render partial: "users/current_company_form" %>

        <%= render partial: "shared/message" %>

        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</main>
```

/users/_current_company_form.html.erb:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= form_for edit_user_registration_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.collection_select :current_company, current_user.moderator_connections(:company_id), :name, :id,{ prompt: "Choose a company" } %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :current_company, :value => current_user.moderator_connections(:company_id) %>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It already goes wrong with the rendering of the partial, I receive the following error (depending on the page I'm in): `No route matches [POST] "/pages/welcome"`

To be honest, I have no idea how to create this (as you can conclude from my foolish attempts). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I think this should work:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= form_for current_user, url: edit_user_registration_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.collection_select(:current_company, current_user.moderated_companies, :id, :name, prompt: "Select a company") %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if that works, though!

**UPDATE**

I think you should change to use:

```
#user.rb
has_many :moderated_companies, through: :moderator_connections, source: :company

#company.rb
has_many :moderators, through: :moderator_connections, source: :user
```

Comment: Dear @oreoluwa, thank you for your reply. I'm getting a new error: `Could not find the source association(s) "moderated_company" or :moderated_companies in model ModeratorConnection. Try 'has_many :moderated_companies, :through => :moderator_connections, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or company?`
It seems like my associations aren't properly aligned yet. Any ideas on how to add the proper assiociations?

Comment: Yes, much better! Still an error (`No route matches [PATCH] "/users/edit"`). Do I have to manually have to add a Patch-route to my routes?

Comment: that's due to the path you're setting for your form. Do you have a custom users_controller?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is that something I shouldn't do?

Comment: If you have the users_controller, change your path to edit_user_path(current_user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117338/discussion-between-sebastian-plasschaert-and-oreoluwa).